# What is the most elegant way to specifiy a start case for recursion?

Tags: functional-style, recursion

When writing recursive code that computes the least value at which a condition is true and various other scenarios it is often necessary to specify a base case. What I have done to supply this is create a function parameter that must always have the specified base case passed into it:

`least2nbigger[x_, n_] := If[2^n >= x, 2^n, least2nbigger[x, 1 + n]]`

This is used with a structure like

`least2nbigger[4097, 1]`

Where the 1 is the start value for the recursion. x is the only parameter of interest to someone using the function; n is always to be passed as 1.

In SML I would do something like this:

```
fun least2nbigger x = least2nbigger (x, 1)
|   least2nbigger (x, n) =
let
    p = pow (2, n)
in
    if p > x then p 
    else least2nbigger (x, n+1)    
end;
```

(My SML is a bit rusty, that might not be entirely valid but the idea is clear).

There is an alternative definition provided for the recursive case; the function can be called without the tuple.

The only way I see to do this in Mathematica would be to make two functions, the recursive case and a dummy function that calls the recursive case with is base parameter. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: `least2nbigger[x_, n_:1] :=...` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As [Rojo](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/109/rojo) notes in a comment you can make `n` an [`Optional`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Optional.html) parameter with a default value:

```
f[x_, n_: 1] := If[2^n >= x, 2^n, f[x, 1 + n]]

f[4097]
```

> ```
> 8192
> ```

More manually you could use a definition for the single parameter case:

```
g[x_] := g[x, 1];
g[x_, n_] := If[2^n >= x, 2^n, g[x, 1 + n]]

g[4097]
```

> ```
> 8192
> ```

You can also convert the `If` statement into a [`Condition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Condition.html), e.g.:

```
h[x_] := h[x, 1];
h[x_, n_] /; 2^n >= x := 2^n
h[x_, n_] := h[x, 1 + n]

h[4097]
```

> ```
> 8192
> ```

You may find that this syntax is somewhat more efficient than `If`, `Switch`, etc.